# How to cluster addresses by the distance

Tags: c#, .net

I am looking for an algorithm/library that will help me solve my problem.
I have geocoded addresses with their geographical coordinates. I would like the user to be able to group these addresses according to the number of kilometers entered.

[enter image description here][1]For example:
[grouping example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXIEJ.jpg)

I thought to use the library System.Device to calculate the distance between points a and b.

```
var sCoord = new GeoCoordinate(sLatitude, sLongitude);
var eCoord = new GeoCoordinate(eLatitude, eLongitude);

return sCoord.GetDistanceTo(eCoord);
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to get started with an effective grouping algorithm. Thank you very much for all your help.

Comment: Could you use some kind of k-means clustering perhaps? It doesn’t allow ocerlapping clusters though I think https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering

Comment: The simply divide.  If you have distances 1000,1100,1200,2000,2100,2200 and divide by 1000 as an integer you will get the first three distance = 1 and the last three distances 2.  So you can then group by the number divided by 1000.

Comment: From your image, I'm not entirely sure what grouping you're actually asking for.  From your text, I thought you would provide a point and group all the addresses based on their distance from that point, each group would be a concentric circle which excludes the inner circles, but this is not what your image says.  Your image suggests some kind of k-means grouping, but with overlapping groups!